Is there a python function to make comparison?
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 16
14 def analyze_preparedness(df, variable):
15     urban_counts = df[[f'Urban_{level}' for level in ['Not_at_all', 'Somewhat', 'Quite_bit', 'Very_much']]].loc[df['Variable'] == variable].values[0]
---> 16 rural_counts = df[[f'Rural_{level}' for level in ['Not_at_all', 'Somewhat', 'Quite_bit', 'Very_much']]].loc[df['Variable'] == variable].values[0]
17 p_value = df['P-value'][df['Variable'] == variable].values[0]
19 urban_total = sum(urban_counts)
NameError: name 'variable' is not defined
